# How do I reset IIS Express default mime types / staticContent?

Tags: iis, mime-types, defaults

I had an issue where .json files weren't being sent to clients when doing jQuery $.getJSON calls. It was returning a 404.3 IIS error message that told me to go to my IIS install directory and enter a command:

`appcmd set config /section:staticContent /+[fileExtension='.xyz',mimeType='text/plain']`

where `.xyz` in my case was `.json` and the mimeType was `application/json`.

I then later found out that instead I can simply add a staticContent element in my web.config file which was necessary for my production hosting solution.

```
<staticContent>
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".json" mimeType="application/json" />
</staticContent>
```

So I did that, but then IIS complained about duplicate handling for .json files, so I went back to my IIS installation dir and ran

`appcmd clear config /section:staticContent` which in retrospect was missing an argument for which mimetype to remove.

So now when I try to load my page IIS is giving me the same 404.3 error message, only now it's complaining about the .html extension.

It seems to me that I deleted ALL the default mime types from IIS and now I don't know how to get them back. Can anyone help me?

EDIT Nov 5, 2015: I misspoke above. This is all IIS Express, not IIS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way is to reinstall IIS (including Process Activation Service) which will remove all of your config.
I strongly suggest when you install IIS to copy a backup of ApplicationHost.config with some other name just in case major issues happen and you can restore at least to installation time. Also enable Config History so that IIS automatically copies a backup when there are changes and you can keep N number of copies.

The right way would have been to add a "" before the ". In the case it does not exist in a parent config, IIS will not complain and would work, and if it existed then you will prevent the duplicate issue you saw.

Now at this time, I would instead suggest that you copy the  section from some other IIS. In case that helps, here is mine which I believe is the default that came with Windows 8.1

```
    <staticContent lockAttributes="isDocFooterFileName">
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".323" mimeType="text/h323" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".3g2" mimeType="video/3gpp2" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".3gp2" mimeType="video/3gpp2" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".3gp" mimeType="video/3gpp" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".3gpp" mimeType="video/3gpp" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".aaf" mimeType="application/octet-stream" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".aac" mimeType="audio/aac" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".aca" mimeType="application/octet-stream" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".accdb" mimeType="application/msaccess" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".accde" mimeType="application/msaccess" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".accdt" mimeType="application/msaccess" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".acx" mimeType="application/internet-property-stream" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".adt" mimeType="audio/vnd.dlna.adts" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".adts" mimeType="audio/vnd.dlna.adts" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".afm" mimeType="application/octet-stream" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".ai" mimeType="application/postscript" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".aif" mimeType="audio/x-aiff" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".aifc" mimeType="audio/aiff" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".aiff" mimeType="audio/aiff" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".application" mimeType="application/x-ms-application" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".art" mimeType="image/x-jg" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".asd" mimeType="application/octet-stream" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".asf" mimeType="video/x-ms-asf" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".asi" mimeType="application/octet-stream" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".asm" mimeType="text/plain" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".asr" mimeType="video/x-ms-asf" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".asx" mimeType="video/x-ms-asf" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".atom" mimeType="application/atom+xml" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".au" mimeType="audio/basic" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".avi" mimeType="video/avi" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".axs" mimeType="application/olescript" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".bas" mimeType="text/plain" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".bcpio" mimeType="application/x-bcpio" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".bin" mimeType="application/octet-stream" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".bmp" mimeType="image/bmp" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".c" mimeType="text/plain" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".cab" mimeType="application/vnd.ms-cab-compressed" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".calx" mimeType="application/vnd.ms-office.calx" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".cat" mimeType="application/vnd.ms-pki.seccat" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".cdf" mimeType="application/x-cdf" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".chm" mimeType="application/octet-stream" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".class" mimeType="application/x-java-applet" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".clp" mimeType="application/x-msclip" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".cmx" mimeType="image/x-cmx" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".cnf" mimeType="text/plain" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".cod" mimeType="image/cis-cod" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".cpio" mimeType="application/x-cpio" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".cpp" mimeType="text/plain" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".crd" mimeType="application/x-mscardfile" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".crl" mimeType="application/pkix-crl" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".crt" mimeType="application/x-x509-ca-cert" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".csh" mimeType="application/x-csh" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".css" mimeType="text/css" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".csv" mimeType="application/octet-stream" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".cur" mimeType="application/octet-stream" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".dcr" mimeType="application/x-director" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".deploy" mimeType="application/octet-stream" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".der" mimeType="application/x-x509-ca-cert" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".dib" mimeType="image/bmp" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".dir" mimeType="application/x-director" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".disco" mimeType="text/xml" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".dll" mimeType="application/x-msdownload" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".dll.config" mimeType="text/xml" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".dlm" mimeType="text/dlm" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".doc" mimeType="application/msword" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".docm" mimeType="application/vnd.ms-word.document.macroEnabled.12" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".docx" mimeType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".dot" mimeType="application/msword" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".dotm" mimeType="application/vnd.ms-word.template.macroEnabled.12" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".dotx" mimeType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.template" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".dsp" mimeType="application/octet-stream" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".dtd" mimeType="text/xml" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".dvi" mimeType="application/x-dvi" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".dvr-ms" mimeType="video/x-ms-dvr" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".dwf" mimeType="drawing/x-dwf" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".dwp" mimeType="application/octet-stream" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".dxr" mimeType="application/x-director" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".eml" mimeType="message/rfc822" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".emz" mimeType="application/octet-stream" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".eot" mimeType="application/vnd.ms-fontobject" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".eps" mimeType="application/postscript" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".etx" mimeType="text/x-setext" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".evy" mimeType="application/envoy" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".exe" mimeType="application/octet-stream" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".exe.config" mimeType="text/xml" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".fdf" mimeType="application/vnd.fdf" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".fif" mimeType="application/fractals" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".fla" mimeType="application/octet-stream" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".flr" mimeType="x-world/x-vrml" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".flv" mimeType="video/x-flv" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".gif" mimeType="image/gif" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".gtar" mimeType="application/x-gtar" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".gz" mimeType="application/x-gzip" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".h" mimeType="text/plain" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".hdf" mimeType="application/x-hdf" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".hdml" mimeType="text/x-hdml" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".hhc" mimeType="application/x-oleobject" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".hhk" mimeType="application/octet-stream" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".hhp" mimeType="application/octet-stream" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".hlp" mimeType="application/winhlp" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".hqx" mimeType="application/mac-binhex40" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".hta" mimeType="application/hta" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".htc" mimeType="text/x-component" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".htm" mimeType="text/html" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".html" mimeType="text/html" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".htt" mimeType="text/webviewhtml" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".hxt" mimeType="text/html" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".ico" mimeType="image/x-icon" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".ics" mimeType="text/calendar" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".ief" mimeType="image/ief" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".iii" mimeType="application/x-iphone" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".inf" mimeType="application/octet-stream" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".ins" mimeType="application/x-internet-signup" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".isp" mimeType="application/x-internet-signup" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".IVF" mimeType="video/x-ivf" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".jar" mimeType="application/java-archive" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".java" mimeType="application/octet-stream" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".jck" mimeType="application/liquidmotion" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".jcz" mimeType="application/liquidmotion" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".jfif" mimeType="image/pjpeg" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".jpb" mimeType="application/octet-stream" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".jpe" mimeType="image/jpeg" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".jpeg" mimeType="image/jpeg" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".jpg" mimeType="image/jpeg" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".js" mimeType="application/javascript" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".json" mimeType="application/json" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".jsx" mimeType="text/jscript" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".latex" mimeType="application/x-latex" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".lit" mimeType="application/x-ms-reader" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".lpk" mimeType="application/octet-stream" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".lsf" mimeType="video/x-la-asf" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".lsx" mimeType="video/x-la-asf" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".lzh" mimeType="application/octet-stream" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".m13" mimeType="application/x-msmediaview" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".m14" mimeType="application/x-msmediaview" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".m1v" mimeType="video/mpeg" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".m2ts" mimeType="video/vnd.dlna.mpeg-tts" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".m3u" mimeType="audio/x-mpegurl" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".m4a" mimeType="audio/mp4" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".m4v" mimeType="video/mp4" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".man" mimeType="application/x-troff-man" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".manifest" mimeType="application/x-ms-manifest" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".map" mimeType="text/plain" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".mdb" mimeType="application/x-msaccess" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".mdp" mimeType="application/octet-stream" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".me" mimeType="application/x-troff-me" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".mht" mimeType="message/rfc822" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".mhtml" mimeType="message/rfc822" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".mid" mimeType="audio/mid" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".midi" mimeType="audio/mid" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".mix" mimeType="application/octet-stream" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".mmf" mimeType="application/x-smaf" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".mno" mimeType="text/xml" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".mny" mimeType="application/x-msmoney" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".mov" mimeType="video/quicktime" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".movie" mimeType="video/x-sgi-movie" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".mp2" mimeType="video/mpeg" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".mp3" mimeType="audio/mpeg" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".mp4" mimeType="video/mp4" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".mp4v" mimeType="video/mp4" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".mpa" mimeType="video/mpeg" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".mpe" mimeType="video/mpeg" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".mpeg" mimeType="video/mpeg" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".mpg" mimeType="video/mpeg" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".mpp" mimeType="application/vnd.ms-project" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".mpv2" mimeType="video/mpeg" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".ms" mimeType="application/x-troff-ms" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".msi" mimeType="application/octet-stream" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".mso" mimeType="application/octet-stream" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".mvb" mimeType="application/x-msmediaview" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".mvc" mimeType="application/x-miva-compiled" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".nc" mimeType="application/x-netcdf" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".nsc" mimeType="video/x-ms-asf" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".nws" mimeType="message/rfc822" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".ocx" mimeType="application/octet-stream" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".oda" mimeType="application/oda" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".odc" mimeType="text/x-ms-odc" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".ods" mimeType="application/oleobject" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".oga" mimeType="audio/ogg" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".ogg" mimeType="video/ogg" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".ogv" mimeType="video/ogg" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".one" mimeType="application/onenote" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".onea" mimeType="application/onenote" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".onetoc" mimeType="application/onenote" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".onetoc2" mimeType="application/onenote" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".onetmp" mimeType="application/onenote" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".onepkg" mimeType="application/onenote" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".osdx" mimeType="application/opensearchdescription+xml" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".otf" mimeType="font/otf" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".p10" mimeType="application/pkcs10" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".p12" mimeType="application/x-pkcs12" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".p7b" mimeType="application/x-pkcs7-certificates" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".p7c" mimeType="application/pkcs7-mime" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".p7m" mimeType="application/pkcs7-mime" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".p7r" mimeType="application/x-pkcs7-certreqresp" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".p7s" mimeType="application/pkcs7-signature" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".pbm" mimeType="image/x-portable-bitmap" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".pcx" mimeType="application/octet-stream" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".pcz" mimeType="application/octet-stream" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".pdf" mimeType="application/pdf" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".pfb" mimeType="application/octet-stream" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".pfm" mimeType="application/octet-stream" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".pfx" mimeType="application/x-pkcs12" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".pgm" mimeType="image/x-portable-graymap" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".pko" mimeType="application/vnd.ms-pki.pko" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".pma" mimeType="application/x-perfmon" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".pmc" mimeType="application/x-perfmon" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".pml" mimeType="application/x-perfmon" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".pmr" mimeType="application/x-perfmon" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".pmw" mimeType="application/x-perfmon" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".png" mimeType="image/png" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".pnm" mimeType="image/x-portable-anymap" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".pnz" mimeType="image/png" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".pot" mimeType="application/vnd.ms-powerpoint" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".potm" mimeType="application/vnd.ms-powerpoint.template.macroEnabled.12" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".potx" mimeType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.template" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".ppam" mimeType="application/vnd.ms-powerpoint.addin.macroEnabled.12" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".ppm" mimeType="image/x-portable-pixmap" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".pps" mimeType="application/vnd.ms-powerpoint" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".ppsm" mimeType="application/vnd.ms-powerpoint.slideshow.macroEnabled.12" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".ppsx" mimeType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.slideshow" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".ppt" mimeType="application/vnd.ms-powerpoint" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".pptm" mimeType="application/vnd.ms-powerpoint.presentation.macroEnabled.12" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".pptx" mimeType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".prf" mimeType="application/pics-rules" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".prm" mimeType="application/octet-stream" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".prx" mimeType="application/octet-stream" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".ps" mimeType="application/postscript" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".psd" mimeType="application/octet-stream" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".psm" mimeType="application/octet-stream" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".psp" mimeType="application/octet-stream" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".pub" mimeType="application/x-mspublisher" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".qt" mimeType="video/quicktime" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".qtl" mimeType="application/x-quicktimeplayer" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".qxd" mimeType="application/octet-stream" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".ra" mimeType="audio/x-pn-realaudio" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".ram" mimeType="audio/x-pn-realaudio" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".rar" mimeType="application/octet-stream" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".ras" mimeType="image/x-cmu-raster" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".rf" mimeType="image/vnd.rn-realflash" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".rgb" mimeType="image/x-rgb" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".rm" mimeType="application/vnd.rn-realmedia" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".rmi" mimeType="audio/mid" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".roff" mimeType="application/x-troff" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".rpm" mimeType="audio/x-pn-realaudio-plugin" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".rtf" mimeType="application/rtf" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".rtx" mimeType="text/richtext" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".scd" mimeType="application/x-msschedule" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".sct" mimeType="text/scriptlet" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".sea" mimeType="application/octet-stream" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".setpay" mimeType="application/set-payment-initiation" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".setreg" mimeType="application/set-registration-initiation" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".sgml" mimeType="text/sgml" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".sh" mimeType="application/x-sh" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".shar" mimeType="application/x-shar" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".sit" mimeType="application/x-stuffit" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".sldm" mimeType="application/vnd.ms-powerpoint.slide.macroEnabled.12" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".sldx" mimeType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.slide" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".smd" mimeType="audio/x-smd" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".smi" mimeType="application/octet-stream" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".smx" mimeType="audio/x-smd" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".smz" mimeType="audio/x-smd" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".snd" mimeType="audio/basic" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".snp" mimeType="application/octet-stream" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".spc" mimeType="application/x-pkcs7-certificates" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".spl" mimeType="application/futuresplash" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".spx" mimeType="audio/ogg" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".src" mimeType="application/x-wais-source" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".ssm" mimeType="application/streamingmedia" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".sst" mimeType="application/vnd.ms-pki.certstore" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".stl" mimeType="application/vnd.ms-pki.stl" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".sv4cpio" mimeType="application/x-sv4cpio" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".sv4crc" mimeType="application/x-sv4crc" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".svg" mimeType="image/svg+xml" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".svgz" mimeType="image/svg+xml" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".swf" mimeType="application/x-shockwave-flash" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".t" mimeType="application/x-troff" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".tar" mimeType="application/x-tar" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".tcl" mimeType="application/x-tcl" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".tex" mimeType="application/x-tex" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".texi" mimeType="application/x-texinfo" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".texinfo" mimeType="application/x-texinfo" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".tgz" mimeType="application/x-compressed" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".thmx" mimeType="application/vnd.ms-officetheme" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".thn" mimeType="application/octet-stream" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".tif" mimeType="image/tiff" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".tiff" mimeType="image/tiff" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".toc" mimeType="application/octet-stream" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".tr" mimeType="application/x-troff" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".trm" mimeType="application/x-msterminal" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".ts" mimeType="video/vnd.dlna.mpeg-tts" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".tsv" mimeType="text/tab-separated-values" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".ttf" mimeType="application/octet-stream" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".tts" mimeType="video/vnd.dlna.mpeg-tts" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".txt" mimeType="text/plain" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".u32" mimeType="application/octet-stream" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".uls" mimeType="text/iuls" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".ustar" mimeType="application/x-ustar" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".vbs" mimeType="text/vbscript" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".vcf" mimeType="text/x-vcard" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".vcs" mimeType="text/plain" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".vdx" mimeType="application/vnd.ms-visio.viewer" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".vml" mimeType="text/xml" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".vsd" mimeType="application/vnd.visio" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".vss" mimeType="application/vnd.visio" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".vst" mimeType="application/vnd.visio" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".vsto" mimeType="application/x-ms-vsto" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".vsw" mimeType="application/vnd.visio" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".vsx" mimeType="application/vnd.visio" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".vtx" mimeType="application/vnd.visio" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".wav" mimeType="audio/wav" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".wax" mimeType="audio/x-ms-wax" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".wbmp" mimeType="image/vnd.wap.wbmp" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".wcm" mimeType="application/vnd.ms-works" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".wdb" mimeType="application/vnd.ms-works" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".webm" mimeType="video/webm" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".wks" mimeType="application/vnd.ms-works" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".wm" mimeType="video/x-ms-wm" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".wma" mimeType="audio/x-ms-wma" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".wmd" mimeType="application/x-ms-wmd" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".wmf" mimeType="application/x-msmetafile" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".wml" mimeType="text/vnd.wap.wml" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".wmlc" mimeType="application/vnd.wap.wmlc" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".wmls" mimeType="text/vnd.wap.wmlscript" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".wmlsc" mimeType="application/vnd.wap.wmlscriptc" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".wmp" mimeType="video/x-ms-wmp" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".wmv" mimeType="video/x-ms-wmv" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".wmx" mimeType="video/x-ms-wmx" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".wmz" mimeType="application/x-ms-wmz" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff" mimeType="font/x-woff" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".wps" mimeType="application/vnd.ms-works" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".wri" mimeType="application/x-mswrite" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".wrl" mimeType="x-world/x-vrml" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".wrz" mimeType="x-world/x-vrml" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".wsdl" mimeType="text/xml" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".wtv" mimeType="video/x-ms-wtv" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".wvx" mimeType="video/x-ms-wvx" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".x" mimeType="application/directx" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".xaf" mimeType="x-world/x-vrml" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".xaml" mimeType="application/xaml+xml" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".xap" mimeType="application/x-silverlight-app" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".xbap" mimeType="application/x-ms-xbap" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".xbm" mimeType="image/x-xbitmap" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".xdr" mimeType="text/plain" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".xht" mimeType="application/xhtml+xml" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".xhtml" mimeType="application/xhtml+xml" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".xla" mimeType="application/vnd.ms-excel" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".xlam" mimeType="application/vnd.ms-excel.addin.macroEnabled.12" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".xlc" mimeType="application/vnd.ms-excel" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".xlm" mimeType="application/vnd.ms-excel" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".xls" mimeType="application/vnd.ms-excel" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".xlsb" mimeType="application/vnd.ms-excel.sheet.binary.macroEnabled.12" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".xlsm" mimeType="application/vnd.ms-excel.sheet.macroEnabled.12" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".xlsx" mimeType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".xlt" mimeType="application/vnd.ms-excel" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".xltm" mimeType="application/vnd.ms-excel.template.macroEnabled.12" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".xltx" mimeType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.template" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".xlw" mimeType="application/vnd.ms-excel" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".xml" mimeType="text/xml" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".xof" mimeType="x-world/x-vrml" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".xpm" mimeType="image/x-xpixmap" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".xps" mimeType="application/vnd.ms-xpsdocument" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".xsd" mimeType="text/xml" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".xsf" mimeType="text/xml" />
```

Comment: Note, that it did not allow me to add all content because of length, but here are the remaining ones that did not fit above: <mimeMap fileExtension=".xsl" mimeType="text/xml" />
            <mimeMap fileExtension=".xslt" mimeType="text/xml" />
            <mimeMap fileExtension=".xsn" mimeType="application/octet-stream" />
            <mimeMap fileExtension=".xtp" mimeType="application/octet-stream" />
            <mimeMap fileExtension=".xwd" mimeType="image/x-xwindowdump" />

Comment: And last ones:             <mimeMap fileExtension=".z" mimeType="application/x-compress" />
            <mimeMap fileExtension=".zip" mimeType="application/x-zip-compressed" />

Comment: So I looked at the IIS Express ApplicationHost.config file and all those mime types seem to be specified, and yet I still get the 404.3 Not Found error message from IIS. I'm using Visual Studio to build and run the project, so I presumed that it actually hosts it on IIS, right? Is there any other place that the mime types would be set? IIS Manager tells me all these mime types have an entry type of "inherit", except at the top of the tree on my machine name which lists "Local".

Comment: I even tried uninstalling IIS and (turning off windows features) and Process  Activation Service and reinstalling to no avail. I'm not sure what to do now.

Comment: Ok, things are very different if you are using IIS Express, for that I would say you can open the configuration file, for example: C:\Users\carlosag\Documents\IISExpress\config\applicationhost.config and see if the section is there. If not, you should be able to just delete that file or even the entire C:\Users\carlosag\Documents\IISExpress\ folder and that will be regenerated next time you use IIS Express with a copy of the "master" config in program files.

Comment: I found the IIS applicationhost.config file. Thanks for telling me where to find it. That file indeed is missing the mime types for all the other object types. I tried renaming that file so that IIS Express would regenerate it, but it instead gave me a 500 server error. I ended up just replacing the mime-type portion of the existing config file with the batch of mime values you posted and that did the trick. Thanks so much!

Comment: @nickvans IIS applicationhost.config  or ***IISExpress*** applicationhost.config  ?

Comment: It was iis express, but I've solved my problem by manually adding the mime types I need for now. Once my current project I'll have time to uninstall everything and reinstall iis.